# How to change font color in Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint 2010 Feature Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, fonts, colors, color-scheme

Within VS2010 I'm using a dark/pastel color scheme. SP2010 *Feature Designer* has a *Manifest* tab with a *Preview of Packaged Manifest* read-only XML pane.
As you can see from the two screenshots, there is text in the pane, but it's basically invisible due to the background pane color.

Is there any way to change the font color, from that light gray to something else? I've tried changing several display items within `Tools\Options\Environment\Fonts and Colors` with no luck.

As a last resort, is there a way to change the pane background color? (although I guess it'll change that for the whole VS IDE)

Thanks all.

Feature manifest preview, unselected: [image: Feature manifest preview, unselected]

Feature manifest preview, selected: [image: Feature manifest preview, selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've found a workaround for this ... for whoever (?) might care.

- Download [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://fangdahai.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-update-lookup-column-through.html) extension.
- If you need help choosing some specific UI color, download any desktop color picker tool, i.e. [Just Color Picker](http://annystudio.com/software/colorpicker/).
- From a VS SharePoint project, open some Feature manifest or Package manifest preview so to apply and check the ongoing results.
- From within VS, create a new custom theme based on Default. Sort the items by name and look for the couple `ProjectDesignerBackgroundGradientBegin/End`.
- Change both to some darker color, like `475B7E`.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Being a Dark Theme sort of guy I've settled on using the [Visual Studio 2012 Dark Theme for Visual Studio 2010](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/VS2012DarkFor2010) which provides a great new look for VS2010.

You'll also need to install the [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) and then import the [VS2012-Dark-for-2010.vstheme] file using the Theme, Customize Colors..., Import Theme meu options.